# Defining an Indeterminate Number of Instances of a Class

Tags: c++, class

Oftentimes in a program I am going to write, a user's action is used to create a new instance of a class. I don't know how many instances I will need, so how can I create instances at runtime and have a way to access each one individually? I have searched the forums, but I can't understand any of the answers that have been given (I am still new to C++)

Comment: These are not forums, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array (or [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)) of classes, add any number of object instances to it, and access them using `[]` operator

```
#include <vector>

class A  // class declaration
{
  public:
    A();
    void print();
};

vector <A> v;     // creating vector
v.push_back(A()); // adding instance 0
v.push_back(A()); // adding instance 1
v[1].print(); // accessing instance 1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use a custom class instead of a vector in order to make it easier to manage the multiple classes?

Comment: @Draksis: What do you mean when you say "manage the multiple classes"?

Comment: @Draksis: Of course- but you'd be vastly better off using a Standard-provided class. Doing it properly is quite complex and you'd have to learn a lot about the language.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. Thanks  a lot! (I upvoted your answer as well)

Answer (score 4):

This is called dynamic allocation. It is an extremely broad topic, and the best thing to do is stick to the containers provided by the Standard library- for example, `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of a class is known as an object.  The new keyword in C++ is used to create objects.